# I need to move all files with a specific name from a directory tree into a single directory and give each file a different name

Tags: file-copy

I have a directory with a large number of subdirectories.  Within those subs are files named img_0004.bmp.  I need to copy them all to a new directory and name them some new different name (e.g. img_004_001.bmp, img_004_002.bmp. etc.)

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you researched and tried on your own? [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/656326/edit) your question and include this information. Also, please note that "how-to questions" [are considered off-topic.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Give more Explanation including which OS windows or linux ? what have you been tried any search tutorial and ....

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the files using the `find` command.  Then, send them through a loop to the required destination.

```
i=0
dest="your/file/destination/directory"
for file in $(find . -name image_0004.bmp -print)
do
    mv ${file} ${dest}/image_004_$((i++)).bmp
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Worked and it was useful as it's the first time I write a shell script after decades of using UNIX.